# spiderable alternative with caching?

Tags: meteor

Is there an alternative to meteor's `spiderable` package that caches the phantomjs-rendered pages? I have a site with over 50,000 pages. If I use `spiderable` then not only are the page load times higher than they should be -- which affects search engine performance -- it also bogs down my machine.

I'm OK forking the spiderable package and adding a caching function to it, but if there is an alternative then I'd like to hear about it. I don't want to use the server-side handlebars package, and also Arunoda's great new `ssr` package is not quite for me, because it would still require a good amount of reworking on my app.

Answer (score 1):

If your pages don't change often, you could put a caching reverse proxy like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) in front of your Meteor app. This should relieve a lot of strain on the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and created a cached version of the `spiderable` package.

https://atmospherejs.com/chfritz/spiderable